# TypeError: nock(...).persist(...).log is not a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, nock

I am trying to get more info on why my nock mock is not right, but I can't make the `persist().log()` work.

Here is the test :

```
it("should delete online absentee bid given its id", () => {
            const absenteeBidId = Faker.random.number();
            const absenteeBid = absenteeBidDataBuilder({ id: absenteeBidId });
            const expectedDeletedAbsenteeBid = {
                deleteAbsenteeBid: {
                    id: `${absenteeBidId}`
                }
            };
            const graphqlQuery = {
                query: `mutation {
                    deleteAbsenteeBid(
                        id: "${absenteeBidId}",
                        user_id: "${userId}",
                    ) {
                        id
                        subscription_id
                        amount
                    }
                }`
            };

            nock(onlineApiUrl)
                .persist()
                .log(console.log)
                .delete(`/orders/${absenteeBidId}`)
                .query({ user_id: userId })
                .reply(StatusCodes.OK, absenteeBid);

            return request
                .post(GRAPHQL_URI)
                .set(JWT, token)
                .send(graphqlQuery)
                .then(response => expectGraphqlResponse(response, expectedDeletedAbsenteeBid));
        });
```

Stackoverflow wants me to add some more details to be able to post this question, but I don't know what to tell you more than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.log` was removed in Nock v13 because it didn't provide much info when debugging.
https://github.com/nock/nock/blob/main/migration_guides/migrating_to_13.md#breaking-changes

Instead, you want to use `DEBUG` get more info on why a particular request is not being matched. https://github.com/nock/nock#debugging

Do something like:

```
user@local$ DEBUG=nock.* node my_test.js
```